# Recizing images in css

Tags: html, css, image-resizing

I have a 4 images aligned side by side, with a hover effect with text. This is some of my html code

```
<nav id="border">
<ul class="photo">
<li class="li">
<a href="#">
<figure class="figure">
<img class="img" src="CSS/Imagens/pintura_auto2.jpg"  alt="Image">
<figcaption class="figcaption"><p class="p">Ramo Automovel</p></figcaption>
</figure>
</a>
</li>

<li class="li">
<a href="#">
<figure class="figure">
<img class="img" src="CSS/Imagens/parede/parede32.jpg"  alt="Image">
<figcaption class="figcaption"><p class="p">Construcao Civil</p>    </figcaption>
</figure>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

and this is some of my CSS:

```
#border{
position: absolute; top: 110%; left: 0%;
width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
height: 60%;
border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
background-color: #F2F2F2;
}

.photo {
position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 0%;
margin: auto;
width: 100%; 
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
}

.photo .li {
display: inline-block;
width: 289px;
}

.photo .figure {
height: 300px;
width: 289px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

.photo .img {
display: block;
width: auto;
height: auto;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms;
-moz-transition: all 300ms;
transition: all 300ms;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

The images width and height are 300px. Is there any way to add the images in the style sheet? I want the images to resize when the window size changes and I'm not beeing able to do it. How can i achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: try to use the width only in percentage and it will give you corresponding height and also set on responsive  on other way use media query for different width devices

Answer (score 1):

Different ways to do it:

1. Use Media Queries
2. Use Percentage for width and height as auto

Answer (score 0):

Change in style may help you

```
.photo .figure {
width:100%;
max-width: 289px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem happens when you go mobile, so:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    .figure img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```